# How to convert DateTime to Date in MongoDB for filtering?

Tags: java

I am a newbie to MongoDB and having a hard time querying documents with simple filtering. I would like to ask if what is the equivalent of CAST(datetime AS DATE) of mysql in MongoDB?

here's my code.

"inspection": {"hourbeg": "2020-11-23 10:12:20"}

```
    Bson filters = Filters.and(new BasicDBObject("center.code", code), 
            new BasicDBObject("inspection.hourbeg", transactionDate));
    Bson sorts = Sorts.descending("printedOn");
    
    List<Document> vehicles = collection.find()
            .sort(sorts)
            .filter(filters)
            .into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

Im still trying to understand this Aggregate in MongoDB.

Comment: You mean transactionDate is DateTime. Can you clarify which type of DateTime you are using because there is a lot of DateTime type in java?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. transactionDate format is “yyyy-MM-dd”

Answer (score 1):

Never mind guys, I was able to solve my problem using this method. Might be useful for others as well.

```
    String startDate = transactionDate.toString()+" 00:00:00";
    String endDate = transactionDate.plusDays(1).toString()+" 00:00:00";
    
    Bson gt = Filters.gt("inspection.hourbeg", startDate);
    Bson lt = Filters.lt("inspection.hourbeg", endDate);
    
    Bson andDate = Filters.and(gt, lt);
    
    Bson filters = Filters.and(new BasicDBObject("center.code", code), 
            andDate);
    Bson sorts = Sorts.descending("printedOn");
    
    List<Document> vehicles = collection.find()
            .sort(sorts)
            .filter(filters)
            .into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```